# Regexp. How check number of char after some char

Tags: regex

I have some strings:

> q.0.0.0.1-1111, q.0.0.0.1.tt_0-1111, tes-00000000-1111

And i have regexp for cutting them:

> r'(?<=[^-\s]{7})[^-]+(?=-)|(?<=-)[^-\s]+-'

It regexp cut string start from 7 char to -.

And i get a expected results:

> q.0.0.0-1111, q.0.0.0-1111, tes-1111

But when i have string like:

> q.0.00.0.0-1111, q.0.00.0.0.tt_0-1111

it regexp cut this sting incorrect.

> q.0.00.-1111, q.0.00.-1111, but i expect q.0.00-1111

I know what problem in this part of code

r'(?<=[^-\s]***{7}***)[^-]+(?=-)|(?<=-)[^-\s]+-'

---------------^

How i can check number of chars after 4 char in string, and if number more than 1, change {7} to 6

Comment: What is the tool or language? Is there more logic to it than checking 4, 7 or 6 chars? What if the string changes, does that number also change?

Comment: python. i should get q.0.0.0-1111, in all cases, when i have q.0.00.0.1-1111 or q.0.000.0.1-1111, or q.00.00.0.1-1111. So i always should get q.0.0.0 and -1111. But my regexp broke on cases, when i have number more than 9 in 5 char.

Comment: But in the last part of the question it states `but i expect q.0.00-1111` Is that correct?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes. i make typo in coment. In case, when i have string q.0.00.0.0-1111, q.0.00.0.0.tt_0-1111(strings where 5 char is number more than 9) i expect q.0.00-1111

Comment: @Thefourthbird so, in my regexp I need change {7} to {6} when 5 char is number more than 9. Is it posible?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by number more than 9. Perhaps you mean 2 digits like this? https://regex101.com/r/HERZpV/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird exactly, it is that what i wont from this regexp. )) Pls, paste it to answer, i vote for it and accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could using an alternation for the lookbehind to add asserting 4 chars other than `-` or a whitespace char followed by 2 digits:

```
(?:(?<=[^-\s]{4}\d\d)|(?<=[^-\s]{7}))[^-]+(?=-)|(?<=-)[^-\s]+-
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group for the 2 alternatives

  - `(?<=[^-\s]{4}\d\d)` Assert 4 chars other than `-` or a whitespace char to the left followed by 2 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=[^-\s]{7})` Assert 7 chars other than `-` or a whitspace char to the left
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `[^-]+(?=-)`
- `|` Or
- `(?<=-)[^-\s]+-` Assert `-` to the left and match 1+ chars other than `-` and a whitespace char followed by matching `-`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HERZpV/1)